# using Jquery Tabs in asp.net

Tags: jquery-ui

I need to use jquery tabs in my asp.net website with ajax mode to load data in HTML partials form.I will have 4  tabs with different data sources.I need to load data into a tab only when a user clicks on that particular tab,in HTML partials using ajax mode.I have been googling to find an example on this.I am new to jquery and asp.net.Could someone please help me with  sample code or example to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery-UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) has a specific demonstration on this very issue.

> *Fetch external content via Ajax for the tabs by **setting an href value in the tab links**. While the Ajax request is waiting for a response, the tab label changes to say "Loading...", then returns to the normal label once loaded.*

Which, when used looks like this (note the `href` values of each link):

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Ajax Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Ajax Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu...tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply.I've tried with the above html
In the href I placed  name of my aspx page in place of ajax/content1.html,It did go to that page when I clicked on that tab,but I do not see the  tabs present on the prevous main page,in the redirected aspx page.am I doing correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand. Is your page online?

Comment: soory,my page is not avaliable online.can I replace ajax/content1.html in the <a href="ajax/content1.html">Ajax Tab 1</a>, with the name of my aspx page and in that case will it display my aspx page with Nunc tincidunt,Ajax Tab 1,Ajax Tab 2 tabs ,when I click on the tab corresponding to aspx page?

Comment: You should replace the `href` value with the path to whatever page you would like to load into that tab.